# Getting image band statistics in Google Earth Engine code

Tags: google-earth-engine, statistics

What is the command to get the band statistics (min/max/etc.) for an image? I know I can do it for a region (using `image.reduceRegion`) but I want to have it for the whole image without defining a region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EarthEngine, images are potentially huge (think of the landsat ones, that are spatial-mosaics from landsat tiles), so that I think the only way to compute image statistics is with the image.reduceRegion() way.

You could eventually use image.geometry() to define the region, but: 
 * you might exceed the `maxPixels` count. 
 * the image could be *unbounded* as in the case of the landsat mosaics

Comment: Watch out for "unbounded" images (e.g. Landsat mosaics).  These may throw an error if you use `image.geometry()` as input to `reduceRegion()`: "Provide 'geometry' parameter when aggregating over an unbounded image."